# NSDictionary acess for only one entry

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionary with only one entry in the dictionary.

```
  ___       ___________
 |___| --->|__|__|__|__|  Array of Dictionary
 |___|      __|__
 |___|      |K|V| Dictionary
 |___| 

 Array of Array


My dictionary content is <NSString*, UIImage*>
```

How to retrieve the values of my dictionary.

Code Snippet:

```
for (int i=0 ; i< [imagesToFill count]; i++) {

    NSDictionary* dict = [imagesToFill objectAtIndex:i];

    UIImage*  img =   ??? [dict]  // How to retrive value from above dict which has only 1 entry
    NSString* imgPath =  ??? 

}


 Note: Each dict has <NSString*, UIImage*>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get all keys of a dictionary like that:

```
NSArray *allKeys = [dictionary allKeys];
```

and of course the same is true for all values:

```
NSArray *allValues = [dictionary allValues];
```

And then simply use `objectAtIndex:0` (or `lastObject`) to access your key or value.

The order of both arrays is not defined (i.e. random). This won't be a problem in your case. But keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the key, then you can access the dictionary element for specific key like:

```
UIImage* img = [dict objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

If you don't want to access by key, then you can convert dictionary to array and access its first element like:

```
NSArray * values = [dict allValues];
UIImage* img = [values objectAtIndex:0];
```